# Блокировка подсетей и адресов на VDS

Tags: nginx, vds

Задача - блокировать ряд подсетей и адресов, в идеале полностью, хотя в принципе кроме 80 порта все закрыто и ***в крайнем случае*** можно сузить рамки до веба.

В имеющемся `iptables` есть ограничение по количеству правил, поэтому самый очевидный вариант в чистом виде отметаем.

Можно было попробовать обойти это с `ipset`, но оказалось он не виртуализируется и на vds только горстка ошибок ядра...

Хотел использовать `hosts.deny` как практически идеальный вариант, но оказалось:

> The first thing to remember is that not every network-based
>   application on your machine is compatible with tcpwrappers. The
>   restrictions on hosts.allow or hosts.deny are only valid if they refer
>   to the tcpwrappers library.

Да они просто издеваются! На Windows проще решить задачу, чем на последнем сервере Debian!,- подумал я и написал этот вопрос здесь.
Как в данном случае решить задачу, что еще осталось?

**P.S.**

---

Текущий костыль - инклуд в конфиг `nginx` файла со списком `deny X.X.X.X/8;`
Из неудобств

- все это добро попадает в общие логи (как `error_log`, так и дублируется
  в `access_log`) и сильно мешает.
- в идеальном мире это должно
  фильтроваться *выше уровня вебсервера*

Comment: я думаю, идеальным вариантом будет смена хостера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно, единственно правильным решением станет смена типа виртуализации на KVM, где нужный функционал работает. 
Уже заказал новый сервер.

Answer (score 1):

для *nginx* есть реализация поддержки *tcp wrappers* (`hosts.allow/deny`).

[код на github-е](https://github.com/sjinks/ngx_tcpwrappers)

[инструкция на русском](http://blog.sjinks.pro/security/654-tcpwrappers-support-for-nginx/)

**отказ от ответственности**

работоспособность и «собираемость» кода не проверял, но, судя по заголовкам коммитов, автор время от времени актуализирует код для поддержки новых версий *nginx*.